# Нужно сделать так, чтобы кнопка стала невидимой

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Я пытаюсь написать лаунчер по готовому изображению, вставив в него несколько объектов.

Если вставить простую кнопку над крестиком(Выход), то получится некрасиво, и мне захотелось сделать кнопку невидимой, т.к закрашивать кнопку - не вариант.

Поискал в интернете - найти не смог, поэтому сюда и пишу. 
Собственно, сам вопрос: **Как сделать кнопку `прозрачной`.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часть кода, к которой вопрос относится:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Game(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, s, r, f, d, img, parent):
        super(Game, self).__init__()

        # print(s, r, f, d, img, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        flags = self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        self.setWindowFlags(flags)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 870, 460)
        self.setWindowTitle('Login')

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))
        self.button = QPushButton('End', clicked=self.go_end)

        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        background = QPixmap("SCpng.png").scaled(880, 500)              
        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setBrush(QPalette.Background, QBrush(background))
        self.setPalette(pal)

        self.show()

    def go_end(self):       
        self.hide()
```

Мне не особо нужна помощь в написании программы, мне бы пригодился *простой пример*

Comment: Напишите ваш вопрос на понятном языке и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается. И не забудьте опубликовать пример того, что у вас есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно вас понял. Чтобы кнопка стала невидимой, необязательно делать ее прозрачной. Я предлагаю задать ей нужный цвет фона, чтобы она слилась с основным фоном.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Game(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, s=0, r=0, f=0, d=0, img='Ok.png', parent=None):
        super(Game, self).__init__()

        self.parent = parent
        flags = self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        self.setWindowFlags(flags)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 870, 460)
        self.setWindowTitle('Login')

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))
        self.button = QPushButton(' ', self, clicked=self.go_end)

        # разместите где хотите
        self.button.setGeometry(850, 0, 20, 20)                                  # +++
        # задайте нужный фоновый цвет, чтобы кнопка слилась с общим фоном 
        self.button.setStyleSheet('background-color: #537abb; border: none;')    # +++

        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.label)
# -       self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.button)                                # ???
        background = QPixmap("pano.jpg").scaled(880, 500)             
        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setBrush(QPalette.Background, QBrush(background))
        self.setPalette(pal)


    def go_end(self):       
# -       self.hide()                                                            # ???
        print(' -- go_end --')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # пробуйте с одной из установок или без них, как вам лучше подойдет          # !!!
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Windows'))  
    # или так    
    # app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
    # или без

    w = Game()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]